# How to redirect to different admin page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

I am writing a Wordpress plugin.

I want to perform a redirect (after creating DB records from POST data, etc...) to other ADMIN page.

Neither header("Location: ...) nor wp_redirect() work - i get

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

which comes from obvious reason.

How do I properly perform a redirect in a Wordpress?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On your form action, add 'noheader=true' to the action URL. This will prevent the headers for the admin area from being outputted before your redirect. For example:

```
<form name="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=your-admin-page&noheader=true'); ?>" method="post" id="post">
```

Comment: ... the horror! I just wasted like 4 hours trying to get past this! Why doesn't wordpress suggest adding that to the url? Thanks! I'd upvote a hundred times more if I could.

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to redirect from your plugin admin page to another admin page while using WP add_page* functions then, after processing your request, you can just echo something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = '/whatever_page.php';
</script>
```

This just renders a javascript based redirect to "/whatever_page.php" thus ensuring no trouble with headers already sent by WP as Chris Ballance already said.

Change "/whatever_page.php" to something like "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=whatever_page"

Comment: This should be the last resort!

Answer (score 2):

For a link added with add_submenu_page (or related function), use the returned $hook_suffix to add an action to "load-$hook_suffix" and do the redirect there. This is how you hook to the page load before the output has begun.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was doing it the wrong way.

My code was inside a add_menu_page() inside 
add_action('admin_menu', ...) call

which is probably called later during the request (after page header has been created and displayed).

Moving my code outside of my plugin handles, into main scope worked - it needs some cleanup, and fixes, but redirect works.

Anyway, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that nothing is sent to http output before the redirect takes place.

You can set "window.location('newlocation');" and that will still let you redirect after output has been sent to the browser.

Comment: Try setting window.location and make the redirect with javascript.

Comment: I know that, but output comes from .../wp-admin/menu-header.php:128
which is a standard wordpress file.

I could try ob_start + ob_* - but this seems to be a little hackish.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just have to make sure that wp_redirect() comes before any output has been sent.

Answer (score -1):

Load it into template_redirect.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'myplugin_template_redirect');

function myplugin_template_redirect() {  
   wp_redirect('http://www.example.com/', 301);
}
```

Comment: `template_redirect` is not an available action hook within the WordPress admin backend.